# How do I add the HTML5/JavaScript category to the Netbeans version 8.2 project setup page?

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I am having Difficulty Creating an HTML5/JavaScript Application Project using the Netbeans IDE version 8.2

When I open Netbeans I click on file, new project, and for whatever reason I do not see the category Creating an HTML5/JavaScript. I am currently running Netbeans IDE 8.2. This is for a java/html course I am taking in college and setting this up is kind of the first step.

This is the tutorial we were given and as you can see there is an  HTML/Javascript option to select but I do not see it.
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html

I have looked at the available and installed plugins and donty see it there either.

If this is the wrong area to ask this question please let me know, I am kind of a new user and this appeared to be the place to ask. I did look for other answers to this question but had a little difficulty finding any.

Anyways thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you downloaded the correct edition of the IDE that has access to HTML5/JavaScript? [link to image of correct editions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmNp7.png)

I downloaded the C++ one as a test and the HTML5/JavaScript project option was not available but I installed most of the plugins in the HTML5 category and most of the plugins in the JavaScript category and the project type appeared when the IDE was reloaded. I would suggest either uninstalling and then downloading the correct edition of the IDE or installing the [HTML5 and JS category plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lut0e.png).

Comment: Make sure that the official sources for plugins are checked 'on' under Plugins > Settings - mine weren't by default (Kubuntu 18.04, installed with `apt`. Then search for HTML and install the appropriate plugin.